# electron js with python 3.6, print error on npm start, downgrade python?

Tags: javascript, python, electron

this is my first electron js installation, and I had to download and install its electron, NPM install (in the folder electron), but when at the start, failed.
error on print, or if I had to do python downgrade?

My error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: / whether python version does not match?

Comment: Please do not link to screenshots of error messages; edit your post to include the relevant text.

Comment: you need python v .2.7 https://electron.atom.io/docs/development/build-instructions-windows/ ,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are writing python3 style code. Like when you write `print` It should be `print(...)`

Comment: [my tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2015/12/creating-your-first-desktop-app-with-html-js-and-electron/) npm start and error

Comment: If you don't then please make sure that your `electron js` is taking python3.

Comment: Did you typed? `python gyptest.py`

Comment: I am sure  about that. It's your python version problem. Anyhow you have to fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when installing on windows. Possible solutions:

- First check the versions od npm and node, update it with this commands:

  ```
  curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash
  ```

  Install again node:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install nodejs
  ```

  And update:

  ```
  npm update -g
  ```
- If it doesn't work try to update or reinstall Phyton an put it in global   environment variables path.
- Check the electron git and try to download the last version manually.
- **Other solutions:**

  - Install or reinstall Windows .Net.
  - Install or reinstall Visual Basic c++
  - Update the package dependencies of the node